# Unity3d WebGL loader in WebPack?

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine, webpack

I have a Unity3D WebGL project which comes with a 'UnityLoader.js' file, it is basically a very long variable like so:

```
var UnityLoader=UnityLoader|(........lots of stuff..........)
```

Now if I try to include as require('./Build/UnityLoader.js') I get the error that it could not be found, most likely because it's not bundling in.

I tried using the copy-webpack-plugin to do the deed but to no avail.

My WebPack.config.js is as follows:

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');


var config = {
  module: {}
};
var baseOutput = Object.assign({}, config, {
  entry: {
    app: './src/index.js'
  },
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist',
    hot: true
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist']),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'Output Management'
    }),
    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
  ],
  output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  }
});

var unityOutput = Object.assign({}, config,{
  entry: {
    app: './src/index.js'
  },
  plugins: [
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      {from: 'src/Build/', to: 'Build/'}])
  ],
  output: {
    filename: 'Build/UnityLoader.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  }
});

module.exports = [

  baseOutput, unityOutput
]
```

What I really would like to be able to do is copy the entire contents of UnityLoader.js along with its companion files to the destination directory so that my webpack js can load them all up...